# Problem QUERY function in Google Spreadsheets formula

Tags: google-sheets

I tried this formula:

`=concatenate(query('Scheda Intervento'!C2:K14;"select SUM (K) where (F>= date '2013-01-01' and F <= date '2013-01-31' and C = '" & A2 &"')";0))`

The result is right but it gives me:

> sum
>   35 €

but I want to have

> 35 €

Comment: Use `INDEX` to capture only the second row/result: `INDEX(Your formula),2,1)`

Comment: i tried..it gives me the same error "sum 35€" how can i hide "sum"??

Comment: Please share the doc with us.

Comment: Try this: `INDEX(query('Scheda Intervento'!C2:K14;"select SUM (K) where (F>= date '2013-01-01' and F <= date '2013-01-31' and C = '" & A2 &"')"),2,1)`

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtZwzv4EAc54dExYU2lSakZDN0RiSlBEcFFpNnF6d1E#gid=5 the formula is in "riepilogo totale ore date compensi operatore sheet column "C2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula:

`=INDEX(query('Scheda Intervento'!C2:K13;"select sum (K)

  where (F >= date '2013-01-01' and F <= date '2013-01-31'

  and C = '" & A2 &"')");2;1)`

After that you can perform the `CONCAT` handling.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a label. This is the format:

`LABEL A 'MyLabel'` in this case you just need to eliminate the actual SUM label so you have to set it empty like:

```
LABEL SUM (A) ''
```

Just put it like this:

```
=QUERY('Scheda Intervento'!C2:K14;"select SUM (K) where (F>= date '2013-01-01' and F <= date '2013-01-31' and C = '" & A2 &"') LABEL SUM (K) ''";0)
```